# How to access item data when using the SetColumns method?

Tags: vba, dictionary, outlook

How do I access item data when using the SetColumns method?

I have cached SentOn data with `myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")`.

Item.Body returns “ ”.

```vb
Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Inbox")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Dim CurrDate
    Set CurrDate = Now
    Dim opnTkt
    Dim clsTkt As Integer
    Dim omntrRprt As Integer
    Dim webCht As Integer

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items

    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")

    'Determine date of each message:
    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
        If Month(dateStr) <> Month(Now) Then
            Defaults = Defaults + 1
            'here myItem.Body return "" 
        ElseIf InStr(myItem.Body, "Process started") > 0 Then
            omntrRprt = omntrRprt + 1
        Else
            def = def + 1
        End If
    Next myItem

    'Output counts per day:
    msg = ""
    msgs = "omniture: " & vbCrLf & omntrRprt & "Web Chat:" & webCht & vbCrLf
    MsgBox msgs

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetDate(dt As Date) As String
    GetDate = Year(dt) & "-" & Month(dt) & "-" & Day(dt)
End Function
```

Comment: My idea: you simply found a message with empty body. Just continue iterating through other items.

Comment: An email can have an Html body, a text body, both or neither. As miroxlav says, perhaps this email does not have a body. What do you see if you look at the email via the user interface? Another possibility is the email has an Html body but no text body. If an email has both bodies, Outlook - and other email packages(?) - will display the Html body and ignore the text one. It appears to me that when there is an Html body, the text body has been created by removing the Html formatting. If the text is all in pictures, which is not unknown, there may be nothing left without the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for your solution , actually when we use 'SetColumns()' and set the value of any variable like i have used `myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")`, you cannot access the other properties of that item . so simply remove it and run the code this will work. :)
[please go through the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867643.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Body or HTMLBOdy if you are using SetColumns. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-setcolumns-method-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 :

After applying the SetColumns method on specific properties of the collection, you cannot read other properties of that collection; properties which are not cached are returned empty. You cannot write to any of the properties of that collection either. Alternatively, if you require read-write, fast access to a set of items, use the Table object.

SetColumns cannot be used, and will cause an error, with any property that returns an object. It cannot be used with the following properties:

| AutoResolvedWinner| InternetCodePage| | Body| MeetingWorkspaceURL| | BodyFormat| MemberCount| | Categories| ReceivedByEntryID| | Children| ReceivedOnBehalfOfEntryID| | Class| RecurrenceState| | Companies| ReplyRecipients| | DLName| ResponseState| | DownloadState| Saved| | EntryID| Sent| | HTMLBody| Submitted| | IsConflict| VotingOptions| The ConversationIndex property cannot be cached using the SetColumns method. However, this property will not result in an error like the other properties listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar situation while trying to access Outlook mails via VBA(in excel).
However, it was far more slower in my case: **1 E-mail per sec**!

Anyway, I successfully managed to improve the speed by using the SetColumnns(eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.SetColumns)

I know.. I Know.. This only works for a few properties, like "Subject" and "ReceivedTime" and not for the body!
But think again, do you really want to read through the body of all your emails? or is it just a subset? maybe based on its subject line or 'Receivedtime'?
My requirement was to just go into the body of the email in case its subject matched a specific string.

Hence, I did the below:

I added a second 'Outlook.Items' obj called 'myFilterItemCopyForBody' and applied the same filter I had on the other 'Outlook.Items'. 
so, now I have two 'Outlook.Items' : 'myFilterItem'  and 'myFilterItemCopyForBody' both with the same E-mail items since the same Restrict conditions are applied on both.

'myFilterItem'- to hold only 'Subject' and 'ReceivedTime' properties of the relevant mails (done by using SetColumns)
'myFilterItemCopyForBody'- to hold all the properties of the mail(including Body)

Now, both 'myFilterItem' and 'myFilterItemCopyForBody' are sorted with 'ReceivedTime' to have them in the same order.

Once sorted, both are looped simultaneously in a nested for each loop and pick corresponding properties (with the help of a counter) as in the code below.

```
Dim myFilterItem As Outlook.Items

Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Set myItems = olFldr.Items

Set myFilterItemCopyForBody = myItems.Restrict("@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" > '" & startTime & "' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" < '" & endTime & "'")
    Set myFilterItem = myItems.Restrict("@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" > '" & startTime & "' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" < '" & endTime & "'")

myFilterItemCopyForBody.Sort ("ReceivedTime")
myFilterItem.Sort ("ReceivedTime")

myFilterItem.SetColumns ("Subject, ReceivedTime")

    For Each myItem1 In myFilterItem
        iCount = iCount + 1
        For Each myItem2 In myFilterItemCopyForBody
            jCount = jCount + 1
            If iCount = jCount Then
               'Display myItem2.Body if myItem1.Subject contain a specific string
                'MsgBox myItem2.Body
                jCount = 0
                Exit For
            End If
        Next myItem2
    Next myItem1
```

***Note1:*** Notice that the Body property is accessed using the 'myItem2' corresponding to 'myFilterItemCopyForBody'.

***Note2:*** The lesser the number of times the compiler enters the loop to access the body property, the better! You can further improve the efficiency by playing with the Restrict and the logic to lower down the number of times the compiler has to loop through the logic.

Hope this helps, even though this is not something out new!